# Magento problem in sub admin user for catalog visibility

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin

I am working on magento admin - subadmin setup. When i add a product from subadmin in "Not Visible Individually" Visibility. It is display in same mode in subadmin magento section. But it is display in "Catalog Search" in admin section. I dont know why this is happens. Its a bug and how to fix this functionality.

Comment: Check the store view or website that you are setting visibility, if they are same or not

Comment: where i have to check this?

Comment: Do you have a multi view or multi website magento ?

Comment: Multi website magento setup.